# Why do we still use NSDictionary and NSArrays in swift ios applications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I see a lot of code for swift ios tutorials on the internet still using the old `objective-c` data types like  `NSDictionary` and `NSArrays` instead of using the modern `Array` and `Dictionary` data types that come with Swift.

Most often I see a lot of type casting going on using `as?` etc. I have seen this mostly in examples involving `json` parsing from a webservice.

So why is this? Is this because swift isn't fully compatible withe cocoa touch apis yet? Or is there another reason like performance?

Comment: Objective-C is not going away. The two are bridged. Read the docs again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you used the NSArray and NSDictionary, swift will automatically bridges to their native swift equivalent Array and Dictionary.

By using the Swift native, the performance will be great.

[Please refer the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling code in the Cocoa library that uses NSDictionary and NSArray and Apple isn't going to rewrite all these libraries.

Your question whether Swift is not fully compatible with Cocoa APIs is nonsensical. It is compatible, or you couldn't call Cocoa. But the Cocoa APIs are not changing. Cocoa is a library; it uses and supports the classes that it uses and supports, and using a different programming language isn't going to change that.

Comment: I see so if I have to check the signature on old APIs and if they return NSArray and NSDictionary, that's probably not going to change so I should be downcasting to these data types - Is that what you are saying?

Comment: You can cast between Array and NSArray, Dictionary and NSDictionary, but you need to be aware that they are not the same. An NSArray is an Array of AnyObject. An NSDictionary is Dictionary that maps AnyObject to AnyObject.

Comment: Actually, `NSDictionary` can only map from object that conform to `NSCopying` protocol. The documentation on Swift's `Dictionary` is not complete, so it's not clear if this limitation will exist.